# Scraping a powerBI report embedded on a website with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web, iframe, powerbi

I'm trying to scrape the data off of this website: https://www.transport.nsw.gov.au/data-and-research/drives-reporting-portal/registration-snapshot-report (if you click on page 2 of 2, you can see the powerBI report). it is a public website and it's permitted to use the data.

I can't possibly get my head around it as I am not familiar with anything website-related and the dashboard itself will take ages to scrape manually.

This is what I've got so far but I'm getting timeout errors:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

chromedriver_path = "~/bin/chromedriver"


url = "https://www.transport.nsw.gov.au/data-and-research/drives-reporting-portal/registration-snapshot-report"


powerbi_iframe_selector = "iframe.mapbox"
report_page_selector = ".reportPage"


service = Service(chromedriver_path)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)

iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, powerbi_iframe_selector))
)


driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)


report_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, report_page_selector))
)


time.sleep(10)


report_contents = report_page.get_attribute("innerHTML")
print(report_contents)


driver.quit()
```

and the error:
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x000000010689b598 chromedriver + 4973976
1   chromedriver                        0x0000000106892913 chromedriver + 4938003
2   chromedriver

I've also tried using CSSSELECTOR as per some advice on here and it didn't help.

Would anyone be able to help me with this dire issue?

I've tried using selenium which is the recommended method but I'm getting loads of timeout errors which I've looked online how to solve but have no idea.

Used CSS selector, didn't help:
report_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, report_page_selector))
)

Comment: You can take a report url directly, ie : https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMTkxOGRlYjctZjkxZi00MjVlLWJhYmYtMzk2ZGNiNTczNTJjIiwidCI6ImNiMzU2NzgyLWFkOWEtNDdmYi04NzhiLTdlYmNlYjg1Yjg2YyJ9

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
report_page = WebDriverWait(driver.
switch_to.frame(iframe), 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
report_page_selector))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the error remains the same :(

Comment: Perhaps your element is very big. Try using presenceOfElementLocated, because visibility expect the whole element to be visible in the webpage.